# Adding quotes and a tab to each element in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

How can I add quotes and a tab to every element in a csv file using python?

For example, I want to make this csv sample:

```
TitleA,TitleB,TitleC,TitleD,TitleE,....
Data1,Data2,<null>,Data4,<null>,....
DataX,<null>,<null>,DataY,<null>,....
```

Look like this:

```
"TitleA"    "TitleB"    "TitleC"    "TitleD"    "TitleE"   ....
"Data1"    "Data2"    "<null>"    "Data4"    "<null>"    ....
"DataX"    "<null>"    "<null>"    "DataY"    "<null>"    ....
```

I am essentially converting a csv file into a tab separated file where all the elements are enclosed in single quotes...

Is there a quick method to do this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're doing is converting from one CSV dialect to another, right?

So, you do that by defining two CSV dialects, and creating a reader for one and a writer for the other.

And fortunately, these dialects are both simple enough (the input is even the default) that you don't need to do anything fancy:

```
with open('in.csv', 'r') as infile, open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

In very old versions of Python, you may have to replace that last line with two:

```
    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

See [Dialects and Formatting Parameters](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) for further details.